# Ternux & Python: threading.py IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, multithreading

I am trying to modify a script someone in another language wrote to work in my Termux environment, and I am a newbie with no previous Python experience (I just completed Hello World!)

When I run the script, it crashes with this output:

```py
Exception in thread Thread-1 (XT):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/data/data/com.termux/files/home/testing.py", line 740, in XT
    data=res.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

and when I open the .py file, the relevant section around line 740 looks like this:

```py
        url='https://iplist.cc/api/'+dns
        res = str(ses.get(url,timeout=(30)).text)
        if '"Cloudflarenet"' not in res:
                data=res.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
                data2=data.replace(' ','').replace('"','').replace('\n','')
```

It's a website that assigns a country code to an IP and it's trying to do some kind of parsing by the looks of it - but I am a newbie and definitely beyond anything that makes sense to me

Thanks very much for any assistance!